# How to add a custom svg icon to the Material UI font icon?

Tags: svg, reactjs, material-ui

The icon I am looking for is pretty unique, so I think I'm going to have to create my own. (I'm looking for an icon of a closed door) I found a PNG file similar to what I need, but I need to figure out a way to integrate it with the material ui font icon.

Is there a way to create the js file for it, similar to the ones that exist? Like this one: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/svg-icons/action/accessibility.js
I don't know where the "path" comes from, does anyone know?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The instructions from [Octicons](https://github.com/blog/1106-say-hello-to-octicons) include a section on [adding new icons](https://github.com/primer/octicons#changing-adding-or-deleting-icons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those were created using design tools specifically created for this purpose. Creating path based SVG Icons will take a bit more time if you're unexperienced in the field, however it is most likely you can create your own with some free online tools and a bit of patience.

Once you did (the data doesn't necessarily have to be in `path` format for the SVG, you can create any valid SVG using the available syntax and attributes which you can find info about [right here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial)), you can simply replicate one of those JS files and import / export them wherever applicable and use it in a similar fashion as you would any Material UI one.

Such an online tool could be this one for creating what you need:

http://editor.method.ac/